# Count columns where the value of each column is the lowest across 5 rows

Tags: google-sheets, countif

Google sheets, have Fantasy Football player scores in rows for each of 38 gameweeks over the year.

As another measure of skill, want to know how many times a player has been last or first placed in each of the gameweeks. This is shown below where red is last and green is first placed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ9j7.png)

Have tried Counta, Countif etc including use of Filter function. DO I need to try Query??

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please do not post screenshots of data — [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74984887/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13045193).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample setup and and the respective formulas would be

WON Formula (cell B2)

`=BYROW(INDEX(BYCOL(D2:AO6,LAMBDA(bx,IF((SUM(bx)=0)+(COUNTA(bx)=0),,IF(MAX(bx)=bx,1,))))),LAMBDA(ax,SUM(ax)))`

LOST Formula (cell C2)

`=BYROW(INDEX(BYCOL(D2:AO6,LAMBDA(bx,IF((SUM(bx)=0)+(COUNTA(bx)=0),,IF(MIN(bx)=bx,1,))))),LAMBDA(ax,SUM(ax)))`

-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=BYROW(MAP(B1:Z5,LAMBDA(a,IF(a="",0,IF(a=MIN(INDEX(B1:Z5,,COLUMN(a)-1)),1,0)))),LAMBDA(b,SUM(b)))
```

Change B1:Z5 with your actual range both times it appears. And the -1 next to COLUMN(a) with -2 if it starts IN C column, -3 if it starts in D column and so on

Repeat the same formula changing MIN with MAX for counting maximums